# How to use zip and map to write csv file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, zip

I want to combine a data array x, and a label array y, into one `csv` file. For example:

```
x = ['first sentence', 'second sentence', 'third sentence']
y = [['1', '0', '1'],['1', '1', '0'],['0', '0', '1']]
```

The result in the `csv` file should be (4 column 3 rows):

```
first sentence,1,0,1
second sentence,1,1,0
third sentence,0,0,1
```

My code is:

```
z = map(list, zip(x, (j for j in y)))
```

But the result is not correct, it is still 2 columns. and I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a list comprehension to get the list of rows:

```
>>> x = ['first sentence', 'second sentence', 'third sentence']
>>> y = [['1','0','1'],['1','1','0'],['0','0','1']]
>>> [[a] + b for a, b in zip(x, y)]
[['first sentence', '1', '0', '1'], ['second sentence', '1', '1', '0'], ['third sentence', '0', '0', '1']]
```

or using `map()`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda a, b: [a] + b, x, y))
[['first sentence', '1', '0', '1'], ['second sentence', '1', '1', '0'], ['third sentence', '0', '0', '1']]
```

Comment: I have modifications on the questions for `x`, sorry about that, but could you please have a look?

Comment: Thank you, I saw your edited answer, I will accept it in ten minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Because `(j for j in y)` gives you a tuple `(['1','0','1'],['1','1','0'],['0','0','1'])`, which is somehow the same with the original `[['1','0','1'],['1','1','0'],['0','0','1']]` to use in zip function(they are both iterators).

I think you may apply list comprehension as follows:

```
z = [','.join([name] + values) for name, values in zip(x, y)]
```

which will give you `['first sentence,1,0,1', 'second sentence,1,1,0', 'third sentence,0,0,1']`